# How to "build" string form one property of an object array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains objects, like this:

```js
"exams": [    
    {
      "id": "62b30836e941368db5d0e531",
      "name": "Basic",
      "price": 100
    },
    {
      "id": "62b30836e941368db5d0e532",
      "name": "Full",
      "price": 200
    }
]
```

I need pick only the name property from every object, and build a string, where the elements are "separated" with comma.
Like this:

```
"Basic,Full"
```

I tried the following, but the method built every whole object into the string:

```js
var e = exams.join(",");
```

Comment: Use `map()` before `join()`

Comment: Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the property `name` from each object and then [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the returned array to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using the `.join()` to create a string, you should map the values you want from the array of objects. Like this:

```
exams.map(exam => exam.name)
```

This should return something like: `['Basic', 'Full']`.

Then you do the `join`.

You could do all in one line (also avoid `var`, use `const` instead):

```
const e = exams.map(exam => exam.name).join(',')
```